# AVPlayerItem duration as computed property

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avkit

I need a structure that provides an AVPlayer and video duration once its URL property has been initialized.

This example works, except the duration is always `Nan`, likely because it is computed before the AVPlayerItem has achieved status `.readyToPlay` and then it is never recomputed.

I have tried adding conditionals to ensure AVPlayerItem is ready, but it still returns NaN.

```
struct Video: Hashable {
    
    var url: URL?
    
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        if let url {
            return AVPlayer(url: url)
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    var duration: Double? {
        if let player {
            if let item = player.currentItem {
                return item.duration.seconds
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I really don't think you want a computed property for `player` -- I think you want a *lazy* property. The computed property is going to return a *new* `AVPlayer` each time

Comment: I chose a computed property because I want a new `AVPlayer` each time the URL is changed, in the sense that I want the video displayed in my View to change with the URL. I think a lazy property might be more appropriate for computing the duration?

Comment: It's sort of a strange pattern to do this in a `struct`. If you want a new AVPlayer whenever the URL is changed, I'd make `Video` a `class`, and have a `didSet` on `url` that generates a new `player`

Comment: I've changed the player and duration properties, such that the player is computed with didSet from the url, and the duration is computed with didSet from the player, but the duration still appears to be NaN. I'm also not sure why this pattern is better than re-computing properties without didSet

Comment: In your original example, AVPlayer would get recreated every time someone accessed `player`, which doesn't really sound like what you'd want. For example, in asking for `duration`, the player would get recreated. In terms of the `NaN`, it seems we don't have enough information here (like the media file, for example). Have you stepped through with a debugger to make sure everything is set like you think it should be?

Comment: That makes sense! I wasn't aware that these properties were recomputed on access and not on change. I've come to the conclusion that duration is NaN simply because the player is not ready to have its duration accessed. As you suggested I want a class, which can observe the status and handle changes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback/observing_playback_state

Comment: You can also use a lazy property, like I suggested in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var playerFactory: (URL) throws -> AVPlayer = {
    try AVPlayer(url: $0)
}


let player = try playerFactory(URL(string:"url")!)
```

**Make sure you stop the last video before initiating a new player instance.**